# What is the power set of the set {{∅}}?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The power set, as I was informed, includes the empty set and the set being discussed itself.

I am quite unsure with the answer, specifically with the braces.

It could be **{∅, {∅}}**

or it could be **{∅, {{∅}}}**

If someone could help me clear up my confusion, I would appreciate it.

Comment: What are the possible subsets of said set?

Comment: Hint: this is a one element set. The only element is $\{\varnothing\}$. Now what is the powerset of a one element set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$
\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}
\newcommand{\PP}{\mathcal{P}}
$
You might find it simpler to define $A := \set \varnothing$. This makes it perfectly clear you're dealing with a singleton (namely, one whose sole element is a set containing an empty set), and helps remove confusion about braces.

Then you want to find $\PP(\set A)$. Obviously, this is given by

$$\PP(\set A) = \big\{ \varnothing, \{A\} \big\}$$

After all, $\set A$ has cardinality one, and these are the only subsets of it. But then, recalling what $A$ is,

$$\PP \left(\big\{\{\varnothing\} \big\} \right) = \Big\{ \varnothing, \big\{ \{ \varnothing \} \big\} \Big\}$$

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. :)